# Magento hide / show coupon field in cart page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento, magento-1.7

I'm using Magento 1.7 and I need a solution or at least some directions in order to solve the following issue:

- I want to hide the coupon field in the cart page and replace it with a link that says "Have a coupon? Click here to use it". When the link is clicked, the coupon form should appear and the customer can enter his code.
  I've searched everywhere and I can't find a solution, which seems really weird since everybody is recommending that the coupon field should not be prominent in the cart page.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use jquery slideToggle() method for this. take a look [here](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/). You can also use prototype for this

Comment: Got it to work, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.